# Scaling Image in Android for different screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

In my application am going to display image from remote data base
In database the image is stored as String(i.e)image location
By using image loader class am displaying image in the screen
I want to scale the image according to the screen size ldpi,mdpi,hdpi 
How to perform that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Then the image always takes as much place as possible.

Or you can create different layouts by creating the following folders in your res directory:

- layout-ldpi
- layout-mdpi
- layout-hdpi

In each folder you can create a custom layout.xml file for each screen resolution.

Comment: custom layout means any reference or example toasteR

Answer (score 0):

see first upon the image stored on location must be good in up to match in each resolution means it is in high defination atleast 960*1280 with 480-320 dpi 
then you can set that image into your imageView through imageloader class then you need to use 
**scaleType="fitXY"** property to your image view so it will fit that image as per your image view

now you are thinking **why image stored on location want to be atleast 960*1280 with 480-320 dpi ?**

cause if it is low resolutional image then when you try to show on hdpi or xhdpi it will get distored on these reoslution thats why hope it will clear your all doubts and it will work for you (it worked for me)

Comment: are you sure I tried fitXY but as u said I didnt used  960*1280 with 480-320 dpi

Comment: ya am very sure i also have same requirement and am also using same code like image loader and so on.... and i got perfect result but yes in one function where you use bitmap compression you need to pass 100 as a input instead of 90/80/70 i think your also using same code for imageLoader you will get this issue in it so use 100 as a parameter in bitmap compression

Comment: i also used fitXy as a scale type

Comment: 100 means width of the image view

Comment: no no in imageLoader you will get concept of attaching bitmap to your imageview in that code there will be code who converts image into bitmap but if in that code you use below than 100 value means compression is below than 100% so image quality get degraded so use  100% means imagequality willremains same and it will not get degrade

Comment: ok U said about  960*1280 with 480-320 dpi could you explain this clearly

Comment: 960*1280 with 480-320 dpi means this is the resolution of image with its density which support for xhdpi device so if you save your image with atleast this resolution means it will supports to its lower resolution like hdpi,mdpi,ldpi but if your image is already a low resolutional image liek 320*480 with 160dpi then when you try to display on xhdpi or hdpi that image will get distored cause it is low resolutional image hope it clears your doubts :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59984/discussion-between-user3251646-and-android-is-everything-for-me).

Answer (score 0):

Store the highest quality image in server and handle all other screen related code in your mobile side

use something like this

http://square.github.io/picasso/